# Best way to deploy changes in an HAProxy cluster

Tags: cluster, haproxy, deployment

I have a two-node HAProxy cluster with Keepalived to provide high availability and redundancy. Now I'm trying to figure what is the best way to do changes in the configuration of my HAProxy's. Is there a rsync between the two clusters enough? (also with a command to reload the config on the slave one). Is there any better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - use a configuration management tool like Puppet or Chef - store your config in version control, then the tool can handle distributing it to both servers and doing the graceful restart of the service.

It's probably overkill when you're looking at just this task, but it will be useful throughout your environment.

Comment: i can definately vouch for puppet, as it can easily ensure configuration management is exactly the way you need it across thousands of servers..... you can control all aspects of server, and view changes thru puppet dashboard (ror app)